# Custom UITextField with UILabel multiline support for error text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to create custom UITextField with error label on bottom of it. I want the label to be multiline, I tried `numberOfLines = 0`. But it is not working.

Here is my snippet for the class

```
public class MyTextField: UITextField {
private let helperTextLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
    label.textColor = helperTextColor
    label.numberOfLines = 0

    return label
}()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(errorTextLabel)
}

public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.addSubview(errorTextLabel)
}

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    errorTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY - 20, width: bounds.width, height: 20)
}
public override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 240.0, height: 68.0)
}

public override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    return intrinsicContentSize
}
}
```

I think the root cause is because I set height to 20, but how can I set the height dynamically based on the `errorTextLabel.text` value?

Comment: use `label.sizeToFit()` and try once

Comment: I have tried it and it not works. still get truncated and only 1 line. I think there is problem in the code that hardcoded the height of label to 20 or height of textfield to 68?

Comment: add this and check `label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrap`

Comment: Still don't work, It still show only 1 line.

Comment: Why don't you use autolayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving your label a fixed size.

Not using AutoLayout and giving the textfield and label room to expand it's size when needed.

Personally, if creating this particular control, I would create a UIView with a textfield and a label inside a UIStackView. That way if the label is hidden when there is no error the stackview will automatically adjust the height for you. Then when you unhide it, the view will expand to fit both controls.

A basic example:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class LabelledTextView: UIView {

    private let label = UILabel()
    private let textfield = UITextField()
    private let stackView = UIStackView()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .white
        addSubview(stackView)

        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(textfield)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        textfield.placeholder = "Please enter some text"
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = "Text did not pass validation, Text did not pass validation, Text did not pass validation, Text did not pass validation"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let labelledTextView = LabelledTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 300, width: 300, height: 60))

let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view.addSubview(labelledTextView)
labelledTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
labelledTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
labelledTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vc.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
labelledTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
labelledTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60).isActive = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc.view
```

Comment: do you have any suggestion if I create in that style of code instead of using custom UIView @Scriptable?

Comment: are you using storyboard or creating programmatically? it's harder to show an example with storyboard

Comment: I created it programmatically.

Comment: Try the example. It expands the longer the text is in the label.

Comment: Thank you very much @Scriptable, sorry but I misunderstood when you ask if I create using storyboard or not. 

I actually create the View using storyboard. I tried to copy paste the code in the init frame to init coder, but the label is only show 1 line if I use the storyboard. Do you know what's wrong about it? Sorry for too many question.

Comment: it will be because you are not using auto layout on the parent view. see at the bottom of my playground code where i place the view and add a top, left and right constraints and a greaterThanOrEqual to constraint for the height?.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171457/discussion-between-jefferson-setiawan-and-scriptable).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sizeToFit()`:

```
    errorTextLabel.sizeToFit()
```